# Why is TypeScript inconsistent with Object interface property re-assignment?

Tags: typescript

### Common

```
interface Interface {
  a: number;
}
```

### Scenario 1

```
let var1: Interface = {
  a: 0
};

const temp = {
  a: 1,
  b: 4
};

var1 = temp; // Compiler is fine with this
```

### Scenario 2

```
const var2: Interface = {
  a: 2
};

var2.b = 3; // This won't compile
```

Am I the only one that finds this to be an inconsistency in the way the compiler behaves?

In the first scenario, the compiler doesn't care that the extra `b` property ends up in the `var1` variable.

Yet in the second scenario, the compiler won't permit `var2` to have the extra property.

Why does this inconsistency exist?

Is it feasible to eliminate the inconsistency by either:

- Disallowing the first scenario
- Allowing the second scenario

?

## Edit 1

I appreciate that the current behaviour (consistent or inconsistent, depending on your perspective) has arisen because of trade-offs and is now widely adopted.

Yet is there a way (or is it feasible to provide a means) to opt-into preventing scenario 1 in certain cases?

I think what I'm looking for is kind of nominal typing behaviour, rather than structural.

I appreciate that TypeScript made the decision early on to provide structural typing, but I wonder about the feasibility (being a layperson in field of language design), of providing portions of both (structural and nominal).

---

*This question was created with TypeScript version **2.2.1** in mind.*

Answer (score 4):

The reason that the first scenario is fine with the compiler is that typescript is [based on structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) and the structure of `temp` satisfies the interface `Interface`.

However, if you try to access the `b` property then the compiler will complain:

```
console.log(var1.b); // error: Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Interface'
```

The error message is the same as with your 2nd scenario and that's how it is indeed consistent.

Here's an example of how it's useful:

```
interface Interface {
    a: number;
}

interface BetterInterface {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

function fn(a: Interface) { }

let a: BetterInterface = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
};
fn(a);
```

Notice that `BetterInterface` doesn't extend `Interface`, but the compiler infers that from the structure of the object.

Comment: I'm familiar with the fact that TypeScript uses a structural type system, but my point of inconsistency is focused on property assignment and not property access (as you have in your console example). In my second scenario, why does the compiler care that another property is being defined (not accessed) and yet it doesn't in the first scenario?

Comment: Because letting you write `user.fristName = 'bob';` would be an enormous trap

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I agree. That's why if eliminating the inconsistency were feasible, I would move to disallowing scenario 1, for reasons exactly such as your example. That's what I so desperately wish TypeScript would provide. I understand that disallowing scenario 1 would have the potential to require more boilerplate and break backwards compatibility, but I see it as a shame that at least some kind of opt-in feature isn't provided.

Comment: @pleasedesktop Disallowing scenario 1 will be problematic as I showed with my `Interface`/`BetterInterface` example.  The first scenario is basically structural type system, if you understand that typescript uses that then you can't really ask to disallow it...